# Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT cannot exect shell script present during image build time

Tags: docker

I am coding along reading a book called "Docker in Action" by Jeff Nickoloff and Stephen Kuenzli. The task is to deploy a logger program via Dockerfile. It's split into several stages and files:

1. I built a custom base image using `mailer-base.df` instructions named `dockerinaction/mailer-base:0.6`:

   ```
   LABEL maintainer="dia@allingeek.com"
   RUN groupadd -r -g 2200 example && \
       useradd -rM -g example -u 2200 example
   ENV APPROOT="/app" \
       APP="mailer.sh" \
       VERSION="0.6"
   LABEL base.name="Mailer Archetype" \
         base.version="${VERSION}"
   WORKDIR $APPROOT
   ADD . $APPROOT
   ENTRYPOINT ["/app/mailer.sh"]
   EXPOSE 33333
   ```

Please be aware that "/app/mailer.sh" had not been placed into the image yet. I am instructed to do so in later step.

2. Once the image was built successfully I followed the guide outlined in the book by creating `mailer-logging.df`:

   ```
   RUN apt-get update && \
       apt-get install -y netcat
   COPY ["./log-impl", "${APPROOT}"]
   RUN chmod a+x ${APPROOT}/${APP} && \
       chown example:example /var/log
   USER example:example
   VOLUME ["/var/log"]
   CMD ["/var/log/mailer.log"]
   ```

At this stage I had not created any image, I will have continued by creating "mailer.sh", which the ENTRYPOINT mentioned in base image points to.

3. I had created a folder log-impl in a directory where above Docker files are stored and placed "mailer.sh" there with following instructions:

   ```
   printf "Logging Mailer has started.\n"
   while true
   do
       MESSAGE=$(nc -l -p 33333)
       printf "[Message]: %s\n" "$MESSAGE" > $1
       sleep 1
   done
   ```

So the structure looks like this:

[image]

with mailer.sh present in the log-impl folder:

[image]

4. Last task is to create image out of mailer-logging.df and run it like this:

   `docker image build -t dockerinaction/mailer-logging -f mailer-logging.df .\n`

   `docker run -d --name logging-mailer dockerinaction/mailer-logging`

Now the problem is that when I inspect logs of `logging-mailer` container it always returns error:

```
exec /app/mailer.sh: no such file or directory
```

I've tried to add additional slashes to `$APROOT` env variable and also to the `COPY` statement. No use.

Am I missing something? Could you please help me understand how the `ENTRYPOINT` is executed? Is it executed during the base custom image `dockerinaction/mailer-base:0.6` build-time or after the `CMD` arguments are supplied by running container `logging-mailer`?

From my perspective it seems that the authors relies upon `ENTRYPOINT` to be executed once the container is run, but it doesn't seem like so. I did my research but from what I've found I could always see people put `ENTRYPOINT` AND `CMD` in 1 Docker file not 2.

Comment: The ENTRYPOINT is used when the container starts. Docker runs a command that consists of ENTRYPOINT concatenated with the CMD command. You can look at the CMD as parameters for the ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: I am aware of that connection. But I was tasked to supply CMD arguments in second Dockerfile. From experience supplying CMD arguments in second Dockerfile should be fine, but I am still surprised the `/app/mailer.sh` is missing. Do you see any issue in `COPY` statement or `ENV` ?

Comment: If you check the image contents (say, `docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/ls dockerinaction/mailer-logging`), does the script exist?  Is it executable?  Is its very first line a "shebang" line like `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: It does contain the `mailer.sh` and the file itself start with `#!`. As @AbhishekS correctly pointed out `ADD` in base custom image correctly adds the both folders containing different version of `mailer.sh` so the `ls` command also lists additional folders.

Comment: and yes the file is executable

Answer (score 0):

`mailer.sh` will be present in `/app/log-impl/mailer.sh` location since `ADD . $APPROOT` step will add the file in the subfolder.

Solution can be:  `mailer.sh` can be added to the directory where the Dockerfile is present OR `ADD` can be updated to point to the right directory OR `ENTRYPOINT` can be updated to point to the right location.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek I've noticed that ADD there as well and was really wondering why it's set to `.` You are probably right I am yet to test the answer. Will surely mark it as answer, if it does work later today. 

Problem is that this whole exercise is meant to be dynamic. 

In next step, which is not mentioned in my question, I would be placing `mailer.sh` with different instructions and 3rd dockerfile would use `ADD`instead of `COPY` like this:

`ADD ["./live-impl", "${APPROOT}"]` . So in the end Docker is expected to copy the content of those folders where `mailer.sh` are located.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution suggested is not working in both ways

Comment: Can you share the updated Dockerfile and the directory structure?

Comment: It's the same, I just removed `log-impl` and `live-impl` directories and placed mailer.sh into the same folder as docker files are located. For the way of adjusting `ENTRYPOINT` I've commented out `COPY` out of mailer-logging.df` entirely as it was already copied and set the `RUN chmod a+x ${APPROOT}/log-impl/${APP}`

Comment: You are mixing up both the solutions here.

Comment: `FROM debian:buster-20190910
LABEL maintainer="dia@allingeek.com"
RUN groupadd -r -g 2200 example && \
    useradd -rM -g example -u 2200 example
ENV APPROOT="/app" \
    APP="mailer.sh" \
    VERSION="0.6"
LABEL base.name="Mailer Archetype" \
      base.version="${VERSION}"
WORKDIR $APPROOT
ADD . $APPROOT
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/log-impl/mailer.sh"]
EXPOSE 33333`

Comment: `FROM dockerinaction/mailer-base:0.6
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y netcat
# COPY ["./log-impl", "${APPROOT}"]
RUN chmod a+x ${APPROOT}/log-impl/${APP} && \
    chown example:example /var/log
USER example:example
VOLUME ["/var/log"]
CMD ["/var/log/mailer.log"]`

Comment: `docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh dockerinaction/mailer-logging -c "cd log-impl && ls -d $PWD/* && test -x mailer.sh && echo true || echo false"` returns this `/app/log-impl/mailer.sh
true`

Comment: Is this sufficient for you to help me understand? Clearly the files is there but somehow `docker run --rm dockerinaction/mailer-logging` always returns `exec /app/log-impl/mailer.sh: no such file or directory` even if the file is present and executable

Comment: You had mentioned that you have removed the `log-impl` directory was removed and the mailer.sh was moved to the directory where Dockerfile was present. In that case the `ENTRYPOINT` should be `ENTRYPOINT ["/app/mailer.sh"]`

To verify the same, you can add `RUN ls -l` after the `WORKDIR` step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248554/discussion-between-b3t0n-and-abhishek-s).